# Prepay (micro) sim card for data in Thailand

Tags: cellphones, thailand, data-plans, pre-pay

I'm going to be two weeks in Thailand and need a micro-sim for my iPhone (non jail broken). The main use will be data but obviously I will use it for calls and text too.

What are the recommended carriers?
Where can I buy the sim?
What are the rates?

Comment: Is your phone unlocked?  If so, no international SIM is going to work in it.

Answer (score 5):

`Truemove-H` is the Best for you, with fastest and most coverage 850MHz 3G Network in nationwide and very cheap price plan.

Best carrier coverage in Thailand is `AIS` but 3G is a few coverage in nationwide. so your mobile might be switch to EDGE when 3G not available.

Answer (score 4):

When I got a pay-as-you-go SIM card in Thailand, my operator billed by the **minutes used** rather than the amount of data transferred; where 'minutes used' is the duration you are connected for online. (So it often made sense for me to download a file or load a page, then turn off data - because typically data connection remains open whenever your phone browser is - and then go back to the browser to read it. I heard however that now some mobile operator are offering data packs too. There are that many ([just three major ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Asia_Pacific_region#Thailand)), so follow through to their site and see what they have.

Answer (score 4):

The question is old yes, but I'd like to add my thoughts to this.
I have been in BKK and southern region recently, and AIS (usually green color package) worked best IMO. A friend of mine bought a TrueMove (red color package) and it was OK too, but signals were not quite good as AIS.

In the Suvarnabhumi airport, go to the airport rail link. Near the 7-eleven, you'll see an AIS stall. They have the micro SIMs (and they didn't cut a mini SIM for me).

Beware that there are some packages with unlimited data for 2 weeks. The speed is terrible (similar to EDGE). AIS was good enough for Google maps and stuff.

You'll find many Wifi hotspots in Pratunam shopping complexes. I didn't really used data until we move to Pataya, Krabi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answers above you might wanna have a look at [sensorly website.](http://www.sensorly.com/map/2G-3G/TH/Thailand/dtac/gsm_52018#%7Ccoverage)

It should give you general idea on which network will likely to work best based on specific area you are going...

[image]